# Factorial Time Complexity for Permutations

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, factorial

I just want to check whether the following code has factorial time complexity. I.e. O(n!) if n is the number of characters in `my_str`. From my understanding it has, but I might have missed something.

```
def perms(a_str):
    stack = list(a_str)
    results = [stack.pop()]
    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        new_results = []
        for partial in results:
            for i in range(len(partial) + 1):
                new_results.append(partial[:i] + current + partial[i:])
        results = new_results
    return results


my_str = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
print(perms(my_str))
```

Comment: The output has size O(n! * n), so no algorithm can be faster than that. Otherwise, is there a specific reason you think your algorithm might be slower than that?

Comment: @kaya3 Fun fact: `itertools.permutations` might be O(n!) if we allow it to reuse its result tuple. [Benchmark](https://tio.run/##nZDBbgMhDETvfIWPEK2qrNJDVSnfgmhitpYWg4z30K/fQtgqOXdu9psZI8qPfme@fBTZ9yg5gVJCUqBUsugxmQchRdGc1/oHC0raNChlrhNQXemGxtwxQrTu00BTzAIFiA9qXyM2uAn4MHaVUOvIL//K33GFYkyAK0jgBe18bnKG22I@w@kE76YX@l44HJeXO3HjWydxguVZqi08fsF2Q7u4pS@U6@ye7xZitTo9Gt6855DQ@8EHc/v@Cw) and [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3390). Not sure about the update algorithm's complexity, though.

Comment: @kaya3 Assuming its cost is proportional to the number of changes from one permutation to the next, it [does seem](https://tio.run/##fZDBTsMwDIbveQrflmjroOEyVeqVK4@AQnFopNYpqYtAE89ekmal22U5JfaX37//4YdbT0@nIcyzDb4HxxjY@24E1w8@MAwY@okNO0/jAZrWOBIL6WPHsA8riJ@x7SfiF5uB3nC7Nq1pIupMJ8Q72iRDHzhKUpWAeNKQsYT6ZpoMCYqM2hh9nyH8ZpnBXMAOeyRetBfvx2TtNW1p3jrMbHnL6nvsRTcgT4HWfWVvBpn2/x@3XbU6wLPpRlRCDAG/ovijsDE2AkeQ7esDlPoSReNHjowk2F/FpOBhyzC@cyLBEUu7O1Nd6d/8tYgui6uE6nOqVseTjYBcHlBAMlLtU1HtVq3FWurP8x8) constant cost per permutation (2.63 changes per permutation).

Comment: @KellyBundy You can get from one permutation to the next in constant time (optimally by just swapping one pair of elements, about 2 changes per permutation). So if you're just trying to run through all n! permutations using an array and swapping in place you can do so in n! time. But if you want to actually do something with each permutation: performing some logic over each element, printing it, copying it out of the in-place array to yield it through a generator, appending a copy to a results array, etc, then you get n\*n! time because each permutation is length n.

Comment: @inordirection Yes, I've read about single-swap permuters, but I was specifically curious about the itertools implementation. And yes, fully using the permutations of course contributes another factor n. About copying the previous result-tuple: That's what my first comment is about. I think it doesn't. If it detects that it has the only reference to the tuple, it changes it in place. Tuples are immutable only from the Python code perspective.

Comment: @KellyBundy That is an interesting built-in optimization! So if you wanted to only process a constant number of values within each permutation it does look like you could use `itertools.permutations` and delete refs in-between iterations to do so O(n!) time. Surprised that you actually have to delete `p` for the optimization though. Would have thought `p` would already be out of scope between iterations so the reference count would be 0 without needing the `del`, but I suppose `p` is normally only being re-assigned between iterations rather than going out of scope?

Comment: @inordirection Yes, or also if you don't use all permutations, e.g., if you randomly sample 1/n of all permutations (and look at each of the sampled ones fully). Loops don't have their own scope in Python. If you don't delete `p`, then it still exists in the next iteration and also after the whole loop.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is actually O((n+1)!), which although pretty comparable to O(n!) is a distinctly greater complexity class than it.

Putting the algorithm into terms amenable to its run-time analysis, its  iteratively generating all permutations of every suffix of the input string until the last iteration of the while loop completes where it will have built permutations of the entire input string.

Before the loop, you generate all permutations of the final, length 1 suffix (just the list containing all 1! = 1 permutations of the final character). For simplicity, consider this the 1st iteration of the loop

Then, during the `k-th` iteration of the loop, you effectively use all previous permutations of the suffix `a_str[n-k+1:]` to build the permutations for the incrementally larger suffix, `a_str[n-k:]` by putting the character at index `n-k` in all possible positions for each partial permutation you've already built. The total work done on each iteration is proportional to the total length of all new partial permutation strings being generated during that iteration, which is the length of each partial permutation, `k`, times the number of partial permutations, `k!`: `k*k!`.

Considering that `k` can range from `1` (when generating the initial single permutation of the last character) to `n` (during the last iteration responsible for generating all of the `n!` permutations which ultimately appear in the output), the total work done over the course of the entire algorithm can be given by the simple sum:

[image]

When you solve this sum, representing the total length of all partial permutations built over the course of the algorithm, you get:

[image]

The optimal run-time of a permutation generating algorithm would be `O(n*n!)`, because that is the total length of the output array you need to produce. However, `O((n+1)!) = O(n*n!)` because:

```
O((n+1)!) = O((n+1)n!) = O(n*n! + n!) = O(n*n!)
```

This means the above algorithm is still asymptotically optimal, even if it does do a bit of unnecessary work in building partial permutations which don't themselves directly figure into the final output (such that permutation generating algorithms based on swapping elements rather than iteratively building partial permutations can be marginally faster).

You can check my math with this instrumented version of the algorithm and some test cases:

```
def perms(a_str):
    total_cost = 0 # total cost of creating all partial permutation strings
    stack = list(a_str)
    results = [stack.pop()]
    total_cost += len(results[0]) # increment total cost
    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        new_results = []
        for partial in results:
            for i in range(len(partial) + 1):
                next = partial[:i] + current + partial[i:]
                total_cost += len(next) # increment total cost
                new_results.append(next)
        results = new_results
    return results, total_cost

from math import factorial

def test(string):
    n = len(string)
    print(f'perms({string}):')
    ps, total_cost = perms(string)
    # print(ps)
    print("optimal cost:", n * factorial(n))
    print("total cost:", total_cost)
    print("expected cost (sum):", sum([k * factorial(k) for k in range(1, n+1)]))
    print("expected cost (closed form):", factorial(n + 1) - 1)
    print()

tests = [''.join([chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'), ord('A')+j)]) for j in range(1, ord('I') - ord('A'))]
for t in tests: test(t)
```