# Why is islice(permutations) 100 times faster if I keep a reference to the underlying iterator?

Tags: python, performance, iterator, iteration, python-itertools

Iterating through `islice(permutations(a), n)` is somehow 100 times faster if I just keep an extra reference to the `permutations` iterator. Alternating between with and without the extra reference:

```
  2.1 ms  with
202.2 ms  without
  2.1 ms  with
195.8 ms  without
  2.1 ms  with
192.4 ms  without
```

What's going on?

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDRasMwDEXf/RV6KXZCKA2hbATyJaMPTqqsBttKbYVtX585djvYYHox0r3HvvLyxTfy3esStm0O5ICNQ8Ng3EKBH53IimEMTGTjU1wwuJU1G/KxAROtmbBYJ7IWpyw8zVe8ryiEhgGC9u@o2hPUNbxUwqdRac5CzBTA6hEtGA9v8sPwTTaQT1pZXqCGrheQyswP4zAUXZb5XnuymK4tmZSaiaAffgVWuqoa8FVm0Eb8l/5D/UAePzmLsfSckPJfymo3XnVfli6eBk47uroRw9AWYgnGs5KH87GdIT0p4QCK04otdsmc16u27Rs)):

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import permutations, islice
from collections import deque

a = range(10 ** 7)
n = 10 ** 5

for label in ['with', 'without'] * 3:
    if label == 'with':
        perms = islice((foo := permutations(a)), n)
    else:
        perms = islice(permutations(a), n)
    next(perms)
    t = timeit(lambda: deque(perms, 0), number=1)
    print('%5.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3), label)
```

Comment: I get "only" a 70x speed up, but that's still inexplicably faster.

Comment: The only difference in the byte code is the insertion of a `DUP_TOP`/`STORE_FAST` pair between the `CALL_FUNCTION` that calls `permutations` and the `LOAD_FAST` that gets `n` for the call to `islice`. I wonder if it's some side effect of `DUP_TOP` that makes the call to `islice` faster?

Comment: Or does `islice` do something weird if its argument has no other reference?

Comment: I don't see any strong difference in timing using `%%timeit` in jupyter and `deque(next(islice((foo := permutations(a)), n), 0))` or `deque(next(islice(permutations(a), n), 0))`

Comment: @mozway Hmm, why did you add that `next`, and what if you don't do that?

Comment: @mozway I think I get it. Not only did you add the `next`, you also made the `0` an argument for the `next` instead of for the `deque`. So what happens is that the `next` returns the first permutation, then you build a deque with the millions of ints, and jupyter probably (I'm not familiar with it) keeps a reference to the deque. So *neither* case pays the price for garbage collecting all those ints, which reduces the difference I observed. And *both* cases pay extra for building that deque, making the remaining difference less significant.

Comment: @Kelly that's a mistake when I typed the comment. I initially tested without the next.

Comment: @mozway I'm able to reproduce it in jupyter, 1.13 ms vs 139 ms. I'm guessing you still did something differently. Can you share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized why. If I don't *don't* keep a reference, then the iterator and all it entails gets garbage collected at the end of timing, and that's included in the time.

Note that the list I build permutations of is very large. So each permutation is very large. So the `permutations` iterator has a large result tuple and internal state data structure, and I also have millions of integer objects from the range. All that must be cleaned up.

When I halve the size of `a` to `a = range(10 ** 7 // 2)`, the times for "without" extra reference drop to about half (100 ms).

When I double the size of `a` to `a = range(10 ** 7 * 2)`, the times for "without" extra reference roughly double (over 400 ms).

Neither change affects the "with" times (always around 2 ms).

---

<sub>In case anyone is wondering why I build permutations of such a large list: I was [looking into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70432422/factorial-time-complexity-for-permutations?noredirect=1#comment124511748_70432422) the time it takes `permutations` to provide all n! permutations of n elements. One might think it needs O(n × n!), since that's the overall result size. But it [reuses and modifies its result tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3390) if it can, so it doesn't build each permutation from scratch but just needs to update it a little. So I [tested that](https://tio.run/##nZDBbgMhDETvfIWPEK2qrNJDVSnfgmhitpYWg4z30K/fQtgqOXdu9psZI8qPfme@fBTZ9yg5gVJCUqBUsugxmQchRdGc1/oHC0raNChlrhNQXemGxtwxQrTu00BTzAIFiA9qXyM2uAn4MHaVUOvIL//K33GFYkyAK0jgBe18bnKG22I@w@kE76YX@l44HJeXO3HjWydxguVZqi08fsF2Q7u4pS@U6@ye7xZitTo9Gt6855DQ@8EHc/v@Cw) with large n in order to see a large speed difference between when it *can* and *can't* reuse its result tuple. It is indeed much faster if it can, and seems to take only O(n!) time to provide all permutations. It appears to on average [change just 2.63 elements](https://tio.run/##fZDBTsMwDIbveQrflmjroOEyVeqVK4@AQnFopNYpqYtAE89ekmal22U5JfaX37//4YdbT0@nIcyzDb4HxxjY@24E1w8@MAwY@okNO0/jAZrWOBIL6WPHsA8riJ@x7SfiF5uB3nC7Nq1pIupMJ8Q72iRDHzhKUpWAeNKQsYT6ZpoMCYqM2hh9nyH8ZpnBXMAOeyRetBfvx2TtNW1p3jrMbHnL6nvsRTcgT4HWfWVvBpn2/x@3XbU6wLPpRlRCDAG/ovijsDE2AkeQ7esDlPoSReNHjowk2F/FpOBhyzC@cyLBEUu7O1Nd6d/8tYgui6uE6nOqVseTjYBcHlBAMlLtU1HtVq3FWurP8x8) from one permutation to the next.</sub>

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense. Either way, `perms` is a reference to the `islice` instance, which has a reference to the `permutations` instance. There shouldn't be any difference between the two regarding what is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @chepner Ugh, you're right. I need sleep. I'll add a note but won't delete, as it does have some things that might help really figure it out.

Comment: @chepner No, wait.... the deque completely exhausts `perms`, i.e., the `islice` instance. So that releases its reference to the `permutations` instance. So I think my answer was right after all, no?

Comment: I just saw that in `deque_extend` while diving into the C implementation. I think I was assuming that with length 0, it wouldn't bother iterating at all. The `consume_iterator` function explicitly calls `finalize_iterator`, which does dereference it.

Comment: So I suspect this is specific to the fact that `deque` is what's consuming the iterator.

Comment: @chepner Ha, sorry about that. I use that all the time in benchmarks, it's the fastest way to fully consume an iterator (see the `consume` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)), and I guess I thought it's well known.

Comment: No, that's fine. It's certainly the trigger, it's just independent of `islice`, which is what I was (overly) focused on at first.